# UWP CalendarDatePicker GetTemplateChild call

Tags: uwp

The following class extends the UWP CalendarDatePicker...

```
public class MyDatePicker : CalendarDatePicker
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _backgroundBorder = base.GetTemplateChild("Background") as Border;

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

What does the `GetTemplateChild("Background")` call do?  It returns a `Border` type evidently (this code is from a Microsoft Github repo), but what is `Background`?  And where are these magic strings defined?

For example, if I were to extend a `TimePicker` in the same manner, what elements are available to me with the `GetTemplateChild` call for a class that extends `TimePicker`?  And how do you figure this out?

I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: That magic string is a hard-coded x:Name given to the TemplateChild(=UIElement being used in the ControlTemplate). Inspecting the default Style defined in [generic.xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources#theme-resources-in-the-resource-dictionary-structure), you'll find all the names you can specify in GetTemplateChild calls.

Comment: Thanks so much.  If you'll post this as the answer I'll mark it as such!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Control's UI is to be instantiated dynamically in runtime by applying [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ControlTemplate) that is pre-defined in Style. "TemplateChild" is a XAML-Element* being used in the ControlTemplate. A certain TemplateChild has a hard-coded x:Name (=magic string). By calling GetTemplateChild() with the name parmeter, you can obtain access to the element.

The default Style to be applied to built-in Control can be found in [generic.xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources#theme-resources-in-the-resource-dictionary-structure). Inspecting the ControlTemplate in the Style for relevant Control, you'll find all the names that you can specify in GetTemplateChild calls.

*XAML-Element: UIElement (or other elements such as Brush, Transform, Storyboard, etc.)